# Python - How to extract elements from an array based on an array of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, extract

Let's say I have a list of elements `X` and one of indices `Y`.

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Y = [0, 3, 4]
```

Is there a function in Python that allows one to extract elements from `X` based on the indices provided in `Y`? After execution, `X` would be:

```
X = [1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
X = [X[index] for index in Y]
```

This is a **list comprehension**; you can look up that topic to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension provided by @Prune is the way to go in pure python. If you don't mind `numpy`, it might be easier just use their indexing scheme:

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.array(X)[Y]
array([1, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.__getitem__` with `map`:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Y = [0, 3, 4]

res = list(map(X.__getitem__, Y))  # [1, 4, 5]
```

Or, if you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
res = X[Y]  # array([1, 4, 5])
```